# Javascript regular expression to find double quotes between certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a string that can be parsed into JSON. The string is dynamically created based on the content in a CMS.
That content could contain HTML markup with double quotes, which confuses the JSON parser. So, I need to replace the double quotes in the HTML with `&quot;` without replacing the double quotes which are actually a part of the JSON structure.
My Idea is to wrap the HTML inside markers, which I could use to identify everything between these markers as the quotes I want to replace.
For instance the string I want to parse into JSON could look like this...

```
str = '{"key1":"XXX<div id="divId"></div>YYY", "key2":"XXX<div id="divId"></div>YYY"}';
```

So, I want to replace every double quote between a XXX and a YYY with a `&quot;`.
Something like...

```
str = str.replace(/XXX(")YYY/g, '&quot;');
```

Hope that made sense. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm going to assume that going back to the CMS and having it/them write JSON _correctly_ is not a valid option? BTW **very crude** `(?:\w+=(")|"(?:\s|>))` though, honesltly, this isn't a job for regex. And, IMHO, if a contract promises to deliver JSON it should. It's like trying to fix a bad CSV with too many commas...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Brad. You're right, this is not a job for regular expressions. It is just an attempt to hack something I cannot fix. You're answer works perfectly for stripping out the quotes surrounding html attributes, but I can't really assume there won't also be quotes in the innerHTML.

Comment: Can't you just get a better JSON parser?  This really shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given Stack Overflow's "we don't do your homework" principles, I don't think I'm going to work through the whole solution, but I can give you some pointers in half-finished code.

```
var xySearch = /this regex should find any text between XXX...YYY/g;
// note the g at the end! That's important
var result;
var doubleQuoteIndices = [];
// note the single-equals. I avoid them when possible inside a "condition" statement,
// but here it sort of makes sense.
while (result = xySearch.exec(str)) {
  var block = result[0];
  // inside of the block, find the index in str of each double-quote, and add it
  // to doubleQuoteIndices. You will likely need result.lastIndex for the absolute position.

}

// loop backwards through str (so that left-side replacements don't change right-side indexes)
// to replace the characters at each doubleQuoteIndices with the appropriate HTML.
```

I kind of find that as great as regex's are for certain patterns, having the programming language do some of the work is often the best solution.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Pull out all the html, adjust each html string individually, then put it back in the origional string. I'll implement this solution. Thank you.